# How to allow single quotes in elasticsearch simple_query_string query

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I am working on implementing Elasticsearch-backed search field on a content website.

[`simple_query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) query type gives me *almost* everything I would want, except one detail: it allows only *double* quote characters for phrase grouping. But I know from hard data that our visitors try to use *single* quotes for exact searches all the time.

Is there a way to allow phrase grouping in ES queries by *both* double and single quotes? Should I write my own query-time analyzer for that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to configure a custom analyzer for the query similar to the current, except with additional mapping character filter, and in the character filter map single quote to a double quote.

Comment: You might want to elaborate. Try for [answer].